# Improving smoothness of multiple jQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I created this multi-layered animation that takes 4 images ("layers") and animates them to "zoom away". It usually runs smoothly but once in a while when the 3rd layer starts, the 2nd layer animation kind of lags. I'm not really sure why/when the lag happens - maybe due to GPU processing?

http://jsfiddle.net/3EwnB/3/

Is there anything I can do to reduce any animation lag?

And if there's a better way to achieve this effect I'm not stuck on using jQuery.animate - alternate suggestions are welcome.

The code for the jQuery animation (for 1 of the 4 layers):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#animation-layer-2').show().animate({
        opacity: '0.9',
        marginLeft: '-490px',
        marginTop: '25px',
        width: '950px'
    }, { duration: 400, queue: false });
}, 500)
```

Also, in the JS Fiddle example, the images are 9-17kb but that actual images I'm using are 131-457kb. The image sizes don't seem to make much of a difference though.

Comment: css animations typically use GPU acceleration, but since the JS just keeps firing something new a whole bunch, it has to re-evaluate in user-land javascript. in short, CSS animations will be much smoother. since it's a mere UI effect, i don't mind leaving IE8 user behind on such bells and whistles...

Comment: Yeah, you're right.
Unfortunately this simple animation is going to be enhanced to show important and valuable information, so we need it to work on IE8/9. I'm not sure what to do. Maybe just ditch the whole animation idea.

Comment: i don't see what you would have to ditch it. you can certainly use slow JQ on IE as a backup if you really really need animation. you can hit the same end style in CSS that works in all browsers, so it's really just a minor transition that would have to be missing of jerky.